# How to create an Object in a specific Entity Group with JPA? (Google AppEngine Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions

I want to use transactions in GAE-J with JPA.

Without JPA it should be:

```
Entity child= new Entity("Child", "ParentKey");
```

but how to do it with JPA?

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String text;
}

@Entity
public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private Parent parent;
    private String text;
}
```

trying...

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
em.persist(parent);
em.refresh(parent);

Child child = new Child();
child.setParent(parent);
em.persist(child);
```

This doesn't work:

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$ChildWithoutParentException:
Detected attempt to establish Child(130007) as the parent of Parent(132001) but the entity identified by Child(132001) has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
```

That sounds a bit back to front...
Am I a blockhead? Or is there an easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

kay... just a little error in my first attempt.

This should work:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String text;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Child.class, mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
}

@Entity
public class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Parent.class)
    private Parent parent;
    private String text;
}
```

Comment: These 2 classes cause enhancer error for me. 
Google AppEngine Enhancer: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Google AppEngine Enhancer: at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.metadata.JPAAnnotationReader.newMetaDataForMember(JPAAnnotationReader.java:1995)
Google AppEngine Enhancer: at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.metadata.JPAAnnotationReader.processMemberAnnotations(JPAAnnotationReader.java:1126)

Comment: Just set up JPA 2 and this works now. But don't you say that this is impossible without back association ?